# wanted to merge the updated "Second" to the "MYJsonObj"

Tags: javascript

I have changed my json using map such as i have deleted some attributes and added some new attributes to MYJsonObj
.Second Now i wanted to merge the updated "Second" to the "MYJsonObj".

```js
 var MYJsonObj={
 "First": [
        {
          "HNo": "1243",
          "Name": "Temp Address",
          "locality": "Temp locality",
           "id":1          
        }],
        "Second": [
        {
          "H.No": "1243",
          "Name": "Temp Address",
          "locality": "Temp locality",
           "id":2          
        }],
         "third": [
        {
          "H.No": "1243",
          "Name": "Temp Address",
          "locality": "Temp locality",
           "id":3          
        }]
        }
```

Comment: your question is unclear .can you elaborate more specific?

Comment: yeah sure@prasanth .

Comment: The above representation shows json with MyJsonObj ,In that object i have added some new attributes /properties  and deleted some old ones .After that a new OBJECT for "SECOND" is created separately .And i have deleted the Old "Second" from MYJsonObj. Now i wanted to add The updated "SECOND" json Object to merge with MyJsonObj as it was before the whole process???please help

Comment: OR YOU CAN ALSO HELP ME OUT BY TELLING ME HOW CAN I MERGE MY NEW JSONARRAY TO MY JSONOBJECT@prasanth

Comment: can you post both object separately

Answer (score 1):

Here you go mate

```js
const originalObj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const modifiedObj = { a: 4, c: 5 };
const finalObj = {};

Object.assign(finalObj, originalObj, modifiedObj);

console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: I have tried this ,this works but i am getting obj without any name the "Second" written as Name is gone now ?@Aleksandar

Comment: If you don't want to change any of the objects that you are merging create new "third" empty one as it is in the example. The result will have the name of the "third" object